# How do I test change text size in simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator, dynamic-text

Apps that support Dynamic Type will adjust to preferred reading size.

The path to that setting on an actual device is:

Settings > Display and Brightness > Text Size
and there is a slider to change the size of text throughout the operating system.

But I seem to not find that setting on a simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Find it with

> Settings>General>Accessibility>Larger Text

[image]